# Jquery Classes and InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm doing is pulling battery voltage and the state of a battery from a Mysql database processing the data in data.php and putting that into a Json array all that is fine. When I get to the Javascript side I get stuck.

2 Questions:
Question 1: How do insert the value into id voltage in html without removing the span?

HTML Code:

```
        <div id="voltState" class="tile-box bg-green">
            <div class="tile-header">
                Battery Status
                <div class="float-right">
                    <i class="glyph-icon icon-bolt"></i>
                    Green
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile-content-wrapper">
                <i class="glyph-icon icon-database"></i>
                <div id="voltage" class="tile-content">
                    <span>volts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Questions 2: class="tile-box bg-green"> I want to replace with the var status from the Javascript so it looks something like class="tile-box bg-(status var here)">

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        sensorData();
    });

    function sensorData(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"data.php",
            data:"json",
            success:function(sensor) {
                //document.write(sensor);
                var volt = sensor[0];
                var status = sensor[1];
                var date = sensor[2];

                document.getElementById('voltage').innerHTML = (volt);
                $("#voltState").toggleClass('bg-green bg-(STATUS VAR HERE??)');
            },
        dataType:'json' 
        });
    }
    setInterval(sensorData, 3000);
```

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: `("bg-green bg-"+status)`

Comment: Q1. use  $('#yourSelector').append( ' your html ' )

Q2. use $('#someSelector').removeClass( 'someClass').addClass( 'someOtherClass')

Comment: Q1. you can do it like this as well: `document.getElementById('voltage').innerHTML += "your html";`

Comment: if you are using jquery you can always use `$("#voltage").html(volt)` instead of `document.getElementById('voltage').innerHTML = (volt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `$("#voltage").append(volt)` or `$("#voltage").prepend(volt)` based on if you want the span before or after the value. In this case I assume you want the span after the volt so you can use the second code. If you would like the value inside a new span you can also use:

> $("#voltage").prepend($("").text(volt));

2. You can store the previous status value in a variable lets say *pastStatus*. So once you have set

`$("#voltState").removeClass('bg-'+pastStatus).addClass('bg-'+status);
pastStatus = status`

**Note:** toggleClass is used when you want to switch between adding and removing the same class. It can't be used in this case since you want to add a class and remove another.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback didn't seem to work after having a play around. I probably didn't do a good job of explaining. will show you how I want to display the volts text:                 

<div id="voltage" class="tile-content">
Volt var here so for example 12.43
                    <span>volts</span> <-- Keep that in place
                </div>

Comment: Prepend does do what I asked for in a way but it doesnt remove the last value so I just end up with loads of volts eg: 12.4312.4312.4312.4312.4312.4312.43 volts

Comment: did you try the prepend on the first line or the one in the fourth? i just noticed the fourth line got changed when i wrote <span> .. 
and yes it would keep the span in place.. but do you need it inside the span? or just before?

Comment: here is a js fiddle of it... https://jsfiddle.net/gwjaufc9/
however if you click it multiple times it is going to keep adding.. 
to stop this you would need another span like this https://jsfiddle.net/gwjaufc9/1/
or you can add the span each time like this https://jsfiddle.net/gwjaufc9/2/

alternatively if it is fine to insert it directly into the span you can also do this 
https://jsfiddle.net/gwjaufc9/3/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help adding it each time worked best I just need to try and get the classes working now. They are 3 classes bg-green orange and red all based on the voltage of battery because they change it doesn't remove the previous class before adding the new one any ideas?

Comment: why doesn't it remove the previous class? did you try my code? is there any other code that also changes the class?

Comment: It was me, it's all working fine with the code you posted thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('voltage').appendChild(volt);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('voltage').innerHTML = '<span>'+volt+'</span>';
```